# Getting data from a DialogFragement, putting it in a SQLiteDB and displaying all results in a recycler view

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I need to send data from a DialogFragment to my FragmentActivity(MainActivity basically) and add it to a SQLiteDB.  Then query all the data to be displayed in the recycler view.  Here is the FragmentActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment);
.....
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    RecyclerView FCRecycler = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.FixedCostsRV);

    Cursor cursor = getAllFixedCosts();
    FCRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new FixedCostsAdapter(this, cursor);

    FCRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    FixedCostsDbHelper dbHelper = new FixedCostsDbHelper(this);

    mDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    readDB = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();


    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

private Cursor getAllCosts() {
    return mDB.query(
            FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
}

public void addCost(String Item, String CostAmount){
    if(Item.length() == 0 ||
            CostAmount.length() == 0){
        return;
    }
        Cost = Integer.parseInt(FixedCostAmount);
    addFixedCostDB(Item, Cost);

    mAdapter.swapCursor(getAllCosts());
}

private long addCostDB(String Item,int Cost) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry.COLUMN_COST_NAME, FixedCostItem);
    cv.put(FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry.COLUMN_COST_AMOUNT, FixedCostItemAmount);
    return mDB.insert(FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

I will also provide the fragmentClass and theDialogFragment in case those can help.
Fragment:

```
    public class FixedCosts extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fixed_costs_fragment, container, false);
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
        Button launchDialog = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.AddNewFixedCostsButton);
        launchDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment dialog = new InfoDialogFragment();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            }
        });

        String amount = (sharedPrefs.getString("AMOUNTMONEY", "WhatsUP"));
        String TextAmount = "$"+amount;

        TextView TitletextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amountTitle);
        TitletextView.setText(TextAmount);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The Fragment has a button that will send you to enter information in a DialogFragment.  Here is the DialogFragmentClass:

```
public class InfoDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public InfoDialogFragment() {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_dialogfrag, null);
    adb.setView(view);
    final EditText itemET = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.getItem);
    final EditText itemAmountET = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.getItemAmount);



            adb
            /*.setIcon()*/
            .setTitle("Fixed Cost")
            .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String FixedCostItem = itemET.getText().toString();
                    String FixedCostItemAmount = itemAmountET.getText().toString();
                    if(FixedCostItem.length() == 0 || FixedCostItemAmount.length() == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Enter Item and Amount", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = new FragmentActivity();
                        fragmentActivity.addFixedCost(FixedCostItem, FixedCostItemAmount);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    InfoDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });
    return adb.create();
}
}
```

SQLiteDB:

```
public class FixedCostsDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "waitlist.db";

public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry.TABLE_NAME;
public static final String ID_COLUMN = FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry._ID;
public static final String COLUMN_COST_NAME = FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry.COLUMN_COST_NAME;
public static final String COLUMN_COST_AMOUNT = FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry.COLUMN_COST_AMOUNT;

public FixedCostsDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String SQL_CREATE_FIXEDCOSTS_DB = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COLUMN_COST_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_COST_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL" +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_FIXEDCOSTS_DB);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + FixedCostsContract.FixedCostsEntry.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

All help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Activity code it seems like you are initializing mDB after calling 
 **Cursor cursor = getAllFixedCosts();**.

**getAllFiexedCosts()** is using mDB variable which is still not initialized. You may get NullPointerException in such case.

Comment: Thank you, I should have caught this.

Answer (score 0):

**I think lot's of bipolerated code can be avoided here!!!**

use `Material Dialogs` for making elegant and simple dialog 
then use `ActiveAndroid` to save data.

*You can do all that stuff in only 20 to 30 lines of code*

---

`MaterialDialogs` https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

`ActiveAndroid` https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid